# Why does Chromium report NXDOMAIN when a domain resolves successfully

Tags: chromium

I was surprised to see this error message in Chromium on Ubuntu 18.04 when trying to view an image in a post on a StackExchange site:

> ## This site can’t be reached
>
> **i.stack.imgur.com**’s server IP address could not be found.
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

In an attempt to find out what was happening I tried to run `tcpdump` to look at the DNS requests and responses. I attempted to reload the image giving me the error and this was the DNS traffic that I saw:

```
# tcpdump -pni any 'port 53'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
20:10:17.618041 IP 127.0.0.1.42714 > 127.0.0.53.53: 3068+ A? i.stack.imgur.com. (35)
20:10:17.618080 IP 127.0.0.1.42714 > 127.0.0.53.53: 23569+ AAAA? i.stack.imgur.com. (35)
20:10:17.618861 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.42714: 3068 13/0/0 CNAME i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net., A 104.16.0.35, A 104.16.26.34, A 104.16.2.35, A 104.16.30.34, A 104.16.28.34, A 104.16.24.34, A 104.16.25.34, A 104.16.29.34, A 104.16.27.34, A 104.16.3.35, A 104.16.1.35, A 104.16.31.34 (277)
20:10:17.619395 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.42714: 23569| 16/0/0 CNAME i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net., AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:1f22, AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:1b22, AAAA 64:ff9b::6810:23, AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:223, AAAA 2001:67c:27e4:64::6810:123, AAAA 64:ff9b::6810:1f22, AAAA 2001:67c:27e4:64::6810:1f22, AAAA 2001:67c:27e4:64::6810:223, AAAA 2001:67c:27e4:64::6810:1b22, AAAA 2001:67c:27e4:64::6810:1922, AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:1d22, AAAA 64:ff9b::6810:123, AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:1e22, AAAA 64:ff9b::6810:1822, AAAA 2001:67c:2b0:db32:0:1:6810:1822 (505)
```

As you can see the DNS resolution succeeded. But Chromium was still showing me the same NXDOMAIN error message. What could cause Chromium to report NXDOMAIN when the lookups were indeed successful?

Comment: I am suspecting a bug in handling of truncated DNS responses. But I don't have definitive evidence of that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See launchpad bugs [1804487](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1804487) and [1805027](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1805027) for the systemd-resolve problem. Workarounds
1) Add package libnss-resolve.
2) Use a nameserver directly in `/etc/resolve.conf` s link (or redirect link from `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf`

Comment: This answer is surely helpful, but it cannot be the full story. As seen from the packet trace in my question only the `AAAA` lookups result in an answer large enough to trigger the bug. Since Chromium supposedly follows [RFC 8305](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8305) the successful `A` lookups should have allowed Chromium to still load the page even if the `AAAA` lookups were failing. I found another quite unexpected workaround. I shut down the DHCP server on my router such that my LAN is effectively IPv6-only, and now I can access `i.stack.imgur.com` without any problems.

Comment: The workaround mentioned in my previous comment worked for Chromium, but later I saw the same problem in `docker`. Then I ran `ln -sf ../run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc` as root. And I haven't seen the problem since.